# Error while getting text into drop down menu from linq using SelectList

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm having an issue populating a drop down menu from a linq query.  Here's my code snippet:

```
theList = new SelectList(from e in db.MyTab
                         join f in db.MyOtherTab on e.TypeId equals MyOtherTab.TypeId
                         select new
                         {
                             Text = e.Name + " "
                                        + e.Code + " "
                                        + f.TypeDescription + " "
                                        + e.Class + " "
                                        + e.Series + " "
                                        + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(e.InterestRate),
                             Value = e.Id
                         }, "Value", "Text");
```

Both `e.Name` and `e.Code` are `varchar(50)` in my table.  The `InterestRate` is a `decimal`, hence the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` function.

`Name`, `Code`, `Class`, `Series` and `TypeDescription` are of type `varchar` in my tables.

This works if `Name`, `Code`, `Class`, `Series` and `TypeDescription` are text or alpha numeric. The problem is that the `SelectList` is populated if `Name`, `Code`, `Class` and `Series` are numbers despite the type being `varchar`.

The drop down list has a blank row if this is the case.

I don't understand why this is.  If it's a varchar it shouldn't matter if it's "123" it is still a varchar, right?  Maybe this isn't the problem but, checking the tables, it's consistent that if ame, Code, Class and Series are numbers the row in the drop drop are blank.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks.

Comment: there's no rule that says you have to do everything in one statement

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't included data, I am guessing that the real issue is null values in the data. That can be cleaned up by doing the query this way:

```
List = new SelectList(from e in db.MyTab
           join f in db.MyOtherTab on e.TypeId equals MyOtherTab.TypeId
           where (e.Name != null &&
                  e.Code != null &&
                  f.TypeDescription != null &&
                  e.Class != null &&
                  e.Series != null &&
                  e.InterestRate != null)
           select new
           {
               Text = e.Name + " "
                      + e.Code + " "
                      + f.TypeDescription + " "
                      + e.Class + " "
                      + e.Series + " "
                      + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(e.InterestRate),
               Value = e.Id
           }, "Value", "Text");
```

There is probably a better way to write the where clauses, but I know this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = (from e in db.MyTab
           join f in db.MyOtherTab on e.TypeId equals MyOtherTab.TypeId
           select new 
           {
               Tab = e,
               OtherTab = f   
           }).ToList();

var list = new SelectList(query.Select(e=>
               new 
               {
                  Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", e.Tab.Name,e.Tab.Code, e.OtherTab.TypeDescription ,e.Tab.Class ,e.Tab.Series ,e.Tab.InterestRate),
                  Value = e.Tab.Id
               }, "Value", "Text");
```